# Indent ONLY the first paragraph of a section/subsection/subsubsecion

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I need to indent only the first paragraph of each section/subsection/subsubsection. Is it possible in a more clever way than using the [`indentfirst`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) package and `\noindent` on each non-first paragraph?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to check our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get th emost out of our site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `\parindent` to 0pt global and after the heading you can add a small horizontal skip by redefining `\@afterheading`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
      \hspace*{1em}%
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

Here an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
      \hspace*{1em}%
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
\section{foobar}

\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]

\section{barfoo}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```