# Indenting the paragraph by .5 inches

Tags: indentation

I am using the indentfirst package. This will only let me indent it by .25inches. How can I indent it by .5 inches?

any help would be great

Comment: Have you tried `\setlength\parindent{.5in}` in the preamble? From the [documentation](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/required/tools/indentfirst.pdf): "Make the first line of all sections etc., be indented *by the usual paragraph indentation.*" So there are no package-specific lengths, just the usual `\parindent`. This will apply to all paragraphs, though, not just the first.

Comment: By the way, the "usual" things are documented in e.g. the LaTeX *unofficial* reference manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a MWE and it is not completely clear whether **all** paragraphs should be equally indented by 0.5in, or you want a **different** indentation for the first paragraph (0.5in), while the others stay at 0.25in. Here's a solution for each case.

### Same indentation for all paragraphs

Since you are loading the package `indentfirst`, adding

```
\setlength\parindent{.5in}
```

to your preamble should do. `indentfirst` does not define any new lengths, [but rather](https://ctan.mc1.root.project-creative.net/macros/latex/required/tools/indentfirst.pdf)

> [makes] the first line of all sections etc., be indented by the usual paragraph indentation

which is given by `\parindent`.

### Special indentation for the first paragraph

Adapting the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113382/), you can set `\parindent` to 0.25pt globally, but redefine `\@afterheading`, so that an additional horizontal space is added to first paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
<...>
\setlength{\parindent}{.25in}  % global indentation

\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
      \hspace*{.25in}%         % special for first paragraphs
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}}
\makeatother
<...>
<document body>
```

In this solution, you won't need to load the package `indentfirst`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{.25in}
\makeatletter
\def\@afterheading{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
      \hspace*{.25in}%
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\kant[1]

\kant[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: the first paragraph after section has a larger indentation]